# selector doesn't return to init

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create a start level label (e.g. 3.2.1.GO), but when I schedule the selector to run according to the Gamestate, and unschedule if gamestate is bigger than X, the selector don;t returns to init selector, and the game remains stopped.

This is my code which is defined on init method:

```
if (startLevelAnimState <=4) {
        [self schedule: @selector(startLevelAnimation) interval:.5];
        NSLog(@"%d", startLevelAnimState);
    } else {
        [self unschedule:@selector(startLevelAnimation)];
    }
```

and this is startLevelAnimation

```
-(void)startLevelAnimation {
    NSLog(@"running startlevelanimation");


    if (startLevelAnimState == 0) {
         NSLog(@"create start level label");
        startLevelLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"3" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:62];
        startLevelLabel.position = ccp(winWidth/2, winHeight*2);

        [self addChild:startLevelLabel z: 10];


        CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:.8 position:CGPointMake(winWidth/2, winHeight*(.65))];
        //CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
        [startLevelLabel runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove]]];
        startLevelAnimState ++;

    } else if (startLevelAnimState ==1) {
        [startLevelLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"]];
        startLevelAnimState ++;

    } else if (startLevelAnimState ==2) {
        [startLevelLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]];
        startLevelAnimState ++;

    } else if (startLevelAnimState ==3) {
        [startLevelLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GO!"]];
        startLevelAnimState ++;

    } else if (startLevelAnimState ==4) {
        CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:.8 position:CGPointMake(winWidth/2, winHeight*2)];
        [startLevelLabel runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove]]];
        startLevelAnimState ++;
        gameState = 1;
        [self unschedule:@selector(startLevelAnimation)];

    }

}
```

Comment: init is only called once during the creation of the layer. You have to create another scheduler to handle the updates in the game.

Comment: do you have another scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

You need set state to 0 instead incrementing. Isn't it obvious?

```
} else if (startLevelAnimState ==4) {
    CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:.8 position:CGPointMake(winWidth/2, winHeight*2)];
    [startLevelLabel runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove]]];
    startLevelAnimState = 0;
    gameState = 1;
    [self unschedule:@selector(startLevelAnimation)];

}
```

Comment: why to restart startlevelAnimState? this would start the animation again